# Send data from between components in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm writting a simple app have 2 screen:
Login and Main.
In file Login.js:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button, StyleSheet, TextInput} from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user_name: '',
            password: ''
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Username:</Text>
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={(text) => {
                    this.setState({user_name: text});
                }}/>
                <Text>Password:</Text>
                <TextInput
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    onChangeText={(text) => {
                    this.setState({password: text});
                }}/>
                <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                    <Button
                        onPress={this.props.click}
                        title="Login"
                        accessibilityLabel="Login to system"/>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

Login.propType = {
    user: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    pass: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-around'
    }
});
```

I have Main.js for renderScene when login successfull.
In file index.android.js, I declare class RouteTest for AppRegistry:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  Alert,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import Main from './Screen/Main.js';
import Login from './Screen/Login.js';
class RouteTest extends Component {
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    switch (route.name) {
      case 'main':
        return (<Main />);
      case 'login':
        return (<Login
          click={()=>{ 
            if(this.state.user_name == 'abc' && this.state.password == '123') { 
              navigator.push({name: 'main'}) 
            } else {
              Alert.alert("Login failed");
            }
          }}/>);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (<Navigator
      initialRoute={{
      name: 'login'
    }}
      renderScene={this.renderScene}/>);
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('RouteTest', () => RouteTest);
```

When I get user_name and password from TextInput of class Login, I using:
this.state.user_name but isn't working.
And my question is: How to get a value of user's input in class Login for class RouteTest.
Thank.

Comment: Seems like your new to this, I suggest looking into a state management lib such as Redux when you're comfortable with react.

Comment: oh, thank you for that suggestion. If not using Redux, do i have another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might want to use [react redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux). Using this u can acess anything from anywhere fast and simple.

Its a little hard to setup but once u have setup its easy to manage and u get info anywhere in the app refer this link: [Getting started with Redux](https://medium.com/@jonlebensold/getting-started-with-react-native-redux-2b01408c0053#.lnbokn6tx).

It covers different aspects of using redux. Starting off with a simple example of counter. It also deals with how to manage an api call where the result can be accessed anywhere from the app.

**UPDATE**: A much quicker solution will be to use React Context API. Here is a [practical example](https://itnext.io/understanding-the-react-context-api-through-building-a-shared-snackbar-for-in-app-notifications-6c199446b80c) . If you want a full fledged state management go with redux instead

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try look at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Basically you can access the `props` of `Login` from your `RouteTest` using refs set, e.g.

```
<Login     
ref={ref => this._login = ref}
/>
```

After that you can access the props like this: `this._login.xxx`